# Modify the Prime Ng time picker default design from up and down arrow to sliders in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datetimepicker, primeng

We are using Prime Ng Time Picker in our application.

Using following code:

`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" showTime="true" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>`

By default it shows time picker with up and down arrows for  changing hour and minutes.

We want to have a slide bars to change hour and minutes respectively.

How can we modify the existing Prime Ng code for date time picker to get sliders instead of up and down arrows.

Comment: You can start your research here -> https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts
However, I do not recommend heavily modifying 3rd party components. If I were you I would create one from scratch to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve with some tweaks. Posting my solution here so that it can help others and my solution can be improved.

I used **ngPrime Slider** inside `<p-footer>` of `<p-calender>`. To keep DateTimePicker and Slider in sync is used `onChange` on sliders and `onInput` on datetimepicker. Used Css to hide default timePicker.

My **app.component.html**:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" class="hide-timer" showTime="true" hourFormat="24" (onInput)="syncTiming()">
  <p-footer>
    Time : {{(hour<10?'0':'')+hour}}:{{(minute<10?'0':'')+minute}}
    <p-slider [(ngModel)]="hour" [min]="0" [max]="23" (onChange)="handleHourChange($event)"></p-slider>
    <p-slider [(ngModel)]="minute" [min]="0" [max]="59" (onChange)="handleMinuteChange($event)"></p-slider>
  </p-footer>
</p-calendar>
```

My **app.component.ts** :

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value= new Date();
  hour=0;
  minute=0;
  handleHourChange=function(event){  // To be called whenever hour value changes
    this.value=new Date(new Date(this.value).setHours(event.value));
  };
  handleMinuteChange=function(event){ // To be called whenever minute value changes
    this.value=new Date(new Date(this.value).setMinutes(event.value));
  };
  syncTiming=function(){   // To called change in time from input field
    if(this.value){
    this.hour=new Date(this.value).getHours();
    this.minute=new Date(this.value).getMinutes();
  }
}
  ngOnInit(){
this.syncTiming()   // initializing hour and minute with initial value of date
}
}
```

My **app.css**:

```
.hide-timer .ui-timepicker{  // for hiding default timepicker
    display:none;
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itkmxt)
Any improvements will be appreciated. I am new to Angular2 :)